# electrostatics particle charging

Tags: electrostatics

When ash particles are charged negatively ( corona charging, ionization, tribo electric ) and then collected on to the fabric; particles arrange themselves in porous dendritic structure whereas without charging particles dont form the porous structure.
What is the physics behind this sort of arrangement of particles?

Answer (score 1):

The process you're talking about is known as [flocculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flocculation), and the particle aggregrates are referred to as flocs. In the [colloid science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_and_colloid_science) world (that's what I used to do) the process is much studied because it's of importance in many industrial applications.

The flocculation and the structure of the flocs is hugely complex because it depends on many different factors, but the general principles are fairly obvious. If the particle-particle interaction is very strong the particles will adhere the moment they collide and you get a very low density fractal type structure. If the particle-particle interaction is weak the particles retain some mobility after they collide, and they are able to rearrange into a denser structure. The lowest energy configuration (for spheres) is for the particles to touch as many other particles as possible, and this leads to a [cubic or hexagonal close packed structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres). In special cases you do see this structure - for example the gemstone  [opal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opal) is formed by close packing of silica spheres - but it's far more common to get low density fractal flocs.

You specifically ask about dust, and to be honest I don't know exactly what the particles in dust are, though I believe it's a mixture of tiny mineral grains and organic matter such as skin cells. I would guess that the difference between electrostatic precipitation of dust and settling under gravity is just the speed of the dust grains as they hit the surface. If dust is settling under gravity this is a slow process and gives the grains a chance to interact with each other at long range before they collide. With an electrostatic precipitator the forces attracting the dust are much strongly so the dust particles will just hit and stick. This would fit with settling under gravity forming a density floc than an electrostatic precipitator.

I have to admit my argument above has a whiff of post-rationalisation about it, but I think that's inevitable given how little I know about dust. However hopefully this will have given you some idea of the physical processes involved and some useful terms to Google.